# resize buffer pixel libjpeg c++

Tags: image-processing, buffer, scale, libjpeg

I have a buffer of pixel (BGRA) of an image in full HD for example (1920x1080). And I would like to scale it in 1280x720.

My buffer is contained in an `unsigned char *`.
How to do it with libjpeg in C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

provide scaling numerator and denominator to the decompression object using scale_num and scale_denom. take a look on jpeg_decompress_struct in jpeglib.h.